# Instagram API: Retrieving the email of currently the logged user

Tags: api, email, request, instagram

Is there a way to retrieve the **email** of **currently logged user** with the **Instagram API**?

This is the response I get to **/v1/users/self**:

```
{  
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data": {
    "username": "...",
    "bio": "",
    "website": "",
    "profile_picture": "...",
    "full_name": "...",
    "counts": {
      "media": 33,
      "followed_by": 9,
      "follows": 0
    },
    "id": "..."
}
```

I couldn't find anything related to permissions or additional options to the request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Similar to twitter API, Instagram will not provide a user's email or other personal information aside from what you are already retrieving.

Reference: [Instagram API docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users)

Comment: Nowadays twitter provides email address after special request